# When should you not report plagiarism?

Tags: ethics, plagiarism

It seems that most of the [ethics](/questions/tagged/ethics) and [plagiarism](/questions/tagged/plagiarism) questions follow the same basic archetype:

> Q: I think there's some plagiarism going on, and I don't really want to report it, but I think I should. Should I?
>
> A: It'll be tricky, but yes, of course you should report it. Consult your institution for more details.

My question: **is there any case of academic dishonesty (including plagiarism) that a student/TA should almost certainly not report?**

Comment: Are you asking when one should refrain from reporting misconduct for *ethical* reasons? For *selfish* reasons? Or both?

Comment: @ff524 *both*, though I guess selfish reasons basically don't count.

Answer (score 5):

When you're not sure is probably one situation. You're accusing someone of dishonesty so you'd better be able to prove it.

Comment: It's not really up to a student "informer" to prove anything. All you can (or should) do if you're reporting possible plagiarism, is describe what you have seen that you think the instructor hasn't, in a non-judgmental and objective way.

Comment: @ff524: I don't know about that, I would be more inclined to keep my mouth shut if I wasn't too sure something is plagiarism. At the very least you risk your reliability as a signal source (aka if you're wrong then people are less likely to care about your thoughts later), and in the worst case the other person is actually innocent and finds out and becomes offended, ruining your relationship in the process.

Comment: @Mehrdad - Yes, but in maths' language, that's the ''trivial solution''. You are right, when OP isn't sure, he _certainly_ should keep quiet. But when he uses the words ''academic dishonesty'' in an in-principle type of a question, isn't it taken for granted that he has reasons to be sure? Then, he's looking for ''non-trivial solutions''.

Comment: @ff524 - But if you don't put the requirement of proving the claims, won't there be too many false, or misguided claims? And all that _whoever-is=the-judge_ will do in a day's work is to attend to frivolous dishonesty complaints.

Comment: @New_new_newbie I don't see why this should create frivolous claims, if everyone acts in good faith. And regardless, it's not a student's job to judge other students; presumably the faculty/adminstration is better equipped to investigate a claim (collect evidence, speak to the student directly, etc.) anyways.

Comment: @ff524 - Because everyone won't act in good faith. What if the claims are used to extract ''revenge'' for a bad viva-voce? You are right, the admins are better placed to judge, but they can certainly reduce their workload if they start asking for some evidence. Or at least, a ''_how do you know ?_'' Otherwise, this is all that they will do in a day's work.

Comment: @New_new_newbie I don't really see malicious accusations of dishonesty as such a common problem that administrators will become overwhelmed by the workload. Perhaps you and I come from different academic cultures...

Comment: @ff524 - It was an in-principle response to an in-principle type of a question. Thankfully, claims of dishonesty aren't that rampant in my ''academic culture'', though a sourcing requirement/ supporting evidence for anything that one claims _is_. Let's leave it at this point, this discussion is becoming ''an extended discussion'' (move-to-chat-type) now. Cheers :)

Comment: _won't there be too many false, or misguided claims?_ — Perhaps in principle, but not in practice.